Magento 2.4.7-p3
So im installing magento, and cant load the site properly
front: https://prnt.sc/L0u_kwbrgLVY  / admin: https://prnt.sc/ZiZzhCCPVgOL

In which system are you install in magento 2 window or Linux or mac

if you install magento 2 ubuntu system then follow all steps below the link. https://www.thecoachsmb.com/install-magento-2-4-5-on-ubuntu-22-04-complete-guide/ If you install magento 2 window system then follow all step below the link. https://www.thecoachsmb.com/100-working-step-by-step-guide-to-install-magento-2-4-4-on-windows/

Since this is a developer local setup, I would recommend setting mode as developer. Also, set ini_set('display_errors', 1); in app/bootstrap.php to see any issues. By default it is commented. If you want to check what all is causing issues then look into the logs - php error log, var/log/system.log, var/log/ecxeption.log. Additionally you can enable template path hint to see which template you are unable to load.
